# Api to make shipping using Priority service in USPS shipping integration

Tags: php

I am integrating `USPS` shipping apis in my module.I got couple of APIs from `USPS` site , but for integration of **Priority Mail , Media Mail , Library Mail** etc. services which API should i need to use.

Right now i found this document for such integration : [Documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/delivery-confirmation-domestic-shipping-label-api.pdf)

Is this API right? -  (
[https:// secure.shippingapis.com /ShippingAPI.dll ?API=DeliveryConfirmationV4 &XML=(see below)](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/delivery-confirmation-domestic-shipping-label-api.pdf))

Comment: Do you have a USPS contact? Generally, when integrating postal services you get an account manager to answer any of your questions.

Comment: i contacted USPS couple of times , but the response from them was not proper.Like i asked them and they replied that i need to give them my userid .

Comment: Then give them your userid. They will probably need to enable priority service against your account, and then they'll tell you how to use the priority service. It's like that for almost all other shipping services.